# Determining reason for QTextDocumentWrite write failure

Tags: qt

Windows 7 SP1
MSVS 2010
Qt 4.8.4

The [QTextDocumentWriter function write](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextdocumentwriter.html#write) only returns a bool.

Is there a way to find out why it failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myTextDocumentWriter->device()->errorString()`

Answer (score 0):

At first glance online, I am not finding any documentation about the state of failure when QTextDocumentWriter::write() returns bool.  Have you tried stepping into the function call to determine the cause of error?

Comment: No, I haven't done that yet. I will do so if I do not get an answer. I understand the specific cause in this case. I want to be able to report the general cause to the user.